# Application on same server environment different users can see each others application forms

Tags: web-applications, dns

My client has the same environment on which a web application resides. Different users of that application are given different ip addresses to login into that environment using a DNS server. The problem is explained below :

When you click a button in a windows application it opens a form (User Details form for example)  of the web application in the web browser.
User A logs in the web application and can see the web application form  opened by User B in his session.Both are logged in in the environment at the same time.
That means some users can see stuff opened by other users  when they are logged into the web browser.

What is the cause of this ? Is it some sort of caching taking place ?
How can this be resolved ?

Comment: Somehow the server is confusing the sessions between the users which means they have the same identification for the session logic (assuming your site has a form of session logic). Are you sure User A is actually using his **own** session?

Comment: You are right it was a session problem. The web application was using the same ipaddress and was sending the request to all the clients on that ipaddress. As this was the same server multiple clients were getting the request. Thank you for your help.